# How to send html email with images background without attaching via PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer for sending emails, and I want to make a custom logo to be in top for my company ,the problem is the logo appear as attachment , Sow i want to know how to embed images in emails without attaching them? Thank you

```
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subbject';
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('logo.png', 'logo');
$mail->Body = '<html><body>';
$mail->Body = '<img src="cid:logo" style="width:100%"></img>';
$mail->Body = '<h3>Bonjour</h3>';
$mail->Body .='</body></html>';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Without attaching with the email? You will need a webserver to host the image ( that you reference with html/css in the email body ). Do you have access to a dedicated webserver for that?

Comment: thanks, no but i tried also a hosted image : http://via.placeholder.com/350x150 instead of logo.png but i got the logo in attachment , by the way im testing on localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of the email must contain a direct link (not a relative link) to an image and that image should be a jpg. eg:

```
<?php
$body .= <<<EOD
<a href='https://my-website.com'><img src='https://my-website.com/image.jpg' alt='logo'></img></a>
EOD;
?>
```

Comment: Note: doesnt have to be a jpg. Could be png, and even gif, in today's email programs, they are widely supported if they can handle html.

Comment: Randall that's not true for Outlook 2007 which is still widely used. jpg's will render but png's do not. One must assume other programs may have limited functionality too and so it is wise to incorporate a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('yourImage.png OR jpeg OR jpg','logo');
$mail->Body = "Hello Mr Martins, the image in this message is  an embedded image .

";